# How do I add custom fields to a task with the Java Asana library?

Tags: java, asana

This is my created task:

```
Task parentTask = client.tasks.createInWorkspace(personalProjects.id)
            .data("name", "taskname"+new Date())
            .data("projects", idList)
            .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, bummer. You caught a bug: although I added the new resources to the Java client library for Custom Fields, the Task model didn't get updated with the new properties at the same time :( Sorry about that. I've created a bug report and we'll get to it with our next round of client library updates.

Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Can you tell me when I can expect the library update? Is there any workaround to add custom fields to a task?